# Is there a cheap service which makes brochures or portfolio books for your work?

Tags: printing, service-recommendation, portfolio

I wonder is there a cheap service, which makes and prints out your portfolio book or brochures? I found a lot of standard brochure printing services, but nothing portfolio based.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at book self publishing services? Lulu.com has a photo book publishing service; you can choose hardcover vs soft cover and I believe a type of paper as well. There are many such publishing services out there but Lulu.com is sort the the mainstream version. [Lulu.com](https://www.lulu.com/s1/photo_books_p/r/studiop/?&cid=~sggl~klulu%20photobooks~gbrand_lulu_photobook_ca_broad~clulu_brand_ca~a6017363061~p&gclid=CLCr_qXijqoCFQQ_bAodRkdrwQ)

Some of these sites also have software you download then you create the publication on your computer rather then on the web.  That being said, it might be, at this point, advantages to design your publication in Illustrator or CorelDraw where you can gain a full control over all the design aspects. Once completed the software prepares your book for publishing; it creates a folder with press files that include all that's needed for professional printers.

Answer (score 1):

I work for Shutterfly.com and we have several styles for professional portfolios. If you go to the custom path book creation process you can choose a 'Portfolio' theme and there are 8 styles including 'Modern Portfolio' which was just released.

Our books are high quality, guaranteed, and competitively priced.

Answer (score 0):

Olympus has a website for this: http://us.ibonthenet.com/store-photobooks.html. See if the price is competitive. The website itself is not greatly designed, <strike>and is slow</strike>.